# Creating defaulted class objects when passed different input arguments

Tags: python, oop, class, constructor

I have two classes `Pair` and `Sequence`. A `Pair` object has two attributes, position and value. A `Sequence` object is a sequence of `Pair` objects.

```
class Pair():
    def __init__(self, position, value):
        self.position = position
        self.value = value
        self.pair = (position, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< Position: {0}, Value: {1} >".format(self.position, self.value)

class Sequence(Pair):
    def __init__(self, pairs):
        self.pairs = pairs
        self.cseg = [pair.value for pair in pairs]
        self.positions = [pair.position for pair in pairs]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< Seq. {0} >".format(" ".join([str(x) for x in self.cseg]))
```

I can create a `Sequence` object with this:

```
>>> Sequence([Pair(0, 2), Pair(2, 8), Pair(3, 1))
< Seq. 2 8 1 >
>>> Sequence.pairs
[< Position: 0, Value: 2 >,
 < Position: 2, Value: 8 >,
 < Position: 3, Value: 1 >]
```

How can I create a `Sequence` object giving only `Pair` values list, like the code below? In this case, `Pair` position must be a sequence from 0 to n - 1, where n is the length of `Sequence`.

```
>>> Sequence([2, 8, 1])
< Seq. 2 8 1 >
>>> Sequence.pairs
[< Position: 0, Value: 2 >,
 < Position: 1, Value: 8 >,
 < Position: 2, Value: 1 >]
```

I tried to use this version of `Sequence`, but it didn't work. I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'

class Sequence(Pair):
    def __init__(self, pairs):

        if not isinstance(pairs[0], Pair):
            self = Sequence([Pair(pos, val) for pos, val in enumerate(pairs)])

        self.pairs = pairs
        self.cseg = [pair.value for pair in pairs]
        self.positions = [pair.position for pair in pairs]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< Seq. {0} >".format(" ".join([str(x) for x in self.cseg]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will create a list of `Pair` objects when you're passing in a list with non-`Pair` objects, otherwise it will simply assign the given list of `Pair` objects to `self.pairs`:

```
class Sequence(Pair):
    def __init__(self, pairs):
        if not isinstance(pairs[0], Pair):
            self.pairs = [Pair(pos, val) for pos, val in enumerate(pairs)]
        else:
            self.pairs = pairs
        self.cseg = [pair.value for pair in self.pairs]
        self.positions = [pair.position for pair in self.pairs]
```

The reason you got the errors is that despite your check on the contents of `pairs`, you are still assigning it to `self.pairs`:

```
class Sequence(Pair):
    def __init__(self, pairs):
        # the following code will run when you're passing a list of integers
        if not isinstance(pairs[0], Pair):
            self = Sequence([Pair(pos, val) for pos, val in enumerate(pairs)])
        # but the next line will also run
        # which means self.pairs` is now a list of integers
        self.pairs = pairs
        # and that means pair in the following line is an int, not a Pair:
        self.cseg = [pair.value for pair in pairs]
        self.positions = [pair.position for pair in pairs]
```

Lastly, you should not do the following in a constructor (assigning to `self`):

```
self = Sequence([Pair(pos, val) for pos, val in enumerate(pairs)])
```

You're trying to 'overwrite' or 'replace' the `self` object but that means you're constructing another `Sequence` object in the constructor of `Sequence`. That is unnecessary in this case because you can handle both cases in the same constructor. That, in turn, leads to much cleaner code.